# Check if SharePoint Permission Group Exists, if not create

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, groups

I am new to doing things in C# coming from PowerShell so I may be missing the obvious, I want to check if a SharePoint Permission Group exists in the `Web` and if not I want to create it and assign it to a parameter I will use later in my script.

However, I cant find an easy check method that returns a `bool` so I just use the `GetByName()` method and check if its `null`, then once its created I assign it to the same parameter I use later `adminGroup` but VS tells me `A local or parameter named cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`

Is there a better way to check for an existing group and how should I handle assigning the `adminGroup` parameter? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
            var web = context.Web;
            // Load required data
            context.Load(web, w => w.SiteGroups.Include(sg => sg.Title), w => w.RoleDefinitions.Include(rd => rd.Name), w => w.Lists);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            // Create Base Libraries
            CreateBaseLibraries();

            // Create Admin Group
            // CHECK IF EXISTS AND ASSIGN PARAMETER OR CREATE?
            var adminGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Employee File Administrators2");
            context.Load(adminGroup);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            if (adminGroup == null)
            {
                CreateAdminPermissionGroup(context, web);
                var adminGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Employee File Administrators2");
            }

            // Create Permission Groups
            var permissionItems = GetListItems(context, web, "Admin_Teams");
            foreach (ListItem item in permissionItems)
            {
                var groupName = item.FieldValues["Title"].ToString();
                CreatePermissionGroup(groupName, adminGroup, "This group is used to administer permissions in the Employee File System");
            }

            // Create Folders

            // Create Content Organiser Rules

        }
    }
```

****EDIT**** Using Muskan's answer I have re-written the section of code below

```
                // Create Admin Group
            Group adminGroup = null;
            try
            {
                adminGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Employee File Administrators2");
                context.Load(adminGroup);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Admin group not found, creating...");
                adminGroup = null;
            }

            if (adminGroup == null)
            {
                CreateAdminPermissionGroup(context, web);
                adminGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Employee File Administrators2");
                context.Load(adminGroup);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Comment: regarding the error message you got from VS: 3 lines above the null check for 'adminGroup' you define the variable but 3 lines below the same if condition you try to declare it again. removing the 'var' before the second declaration should fix that.

Comment: Thanks garglblarg, I changed that in the fix I added too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
SPGroup group = null;

// Check if the group exists
try
{                                     
    group = root.SiteGroups["The Group Name"];
}
catch { }

// If it doesn't, add it
if (group == null)
{
    root.SiteGroups.Add("The Group Name", member, root.Author, "Your Group Description");
    group = root.SiteGroups["The Group Name"];

    // Add the group's permissions
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = root.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
    root.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    root.Update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Muskan using your answer I wrote the code below my question,, as this is for SharePoint online its slightly different, maybe there is a better way but it works.

Comment: Glad that helped you !